# Return a value in php function

Tags: php, random

Hy, I have this code for example:

```
function generateRandStr($length){
      $randstr = "";
      for($i=0; $i<$length; $i++){
         $randnum = mt_rand(0,61);
         if($randnum < 10){
            $randstr .= chr($randnum+48);
         }else if($randnum < 36){
            $randstr .= chr($randnum+55);
         }else{
            $randstr .= chr($randnum+61);
         }
      }
      return $randstr;
   }
```

but when it tried to use on the main:

```
    generateRandStr(10); 
    echo $irandstr;
```

What am I not doing? :(

Comment: You're not assigning the returned value to $irandstr before echoing

Comment: To understand what went wrong, give this text about scopes a read: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: Also hundreds of us edit the PHP manual - for a reason. We cover most parts so you don't need to ask questions about it on Stackoverflow: http://www.php.net/functions.returning-values

Answer (score 5, accepted):

assign the returned result to a variable:

```
$mystring = generateRandStr(10);
```

or pass it to a function:

```
echo generateRandStr(10);
```

Comment: When you see such a question and the user has just joined the site some minutes ago, please leave a comment where the manual is, show where the FAQ of SO is and explain why the question is not useful instead.

Answer (score 2):

assign the value to some variable which u get from the function.

```
$rand_str =  generateRandStr(10); 
echo $rand_str;
```

Comment: Yes, lets answer again and again. I may post the same answer as well.

Comment: if u have anothr way to answer. show...

Comment: And do you have another way to answer, that differs from michi or Harpreet answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can do so by this:

```
echo generateRandStr(10);
```

or

```
$irandstr = generateRandStr(10); 
echo $irandstr;
```

In the above code snippet `$irandstr;` does not have any value assigned.